# При перезаписи данных в тип значения создается новая переменная или нет

Tags: c#, .net

Например, создается переменная
int a=5;
после в коде она изменяется на a=10;
вопрос: в ячейке памяти в стеке, куда было записано 5 изменилось само значение на 10 или выделилась новая область памяти под нее и туда записалась 10 а 5 так и осталась в памяти?

Comment: Заменилось на 10, зачем новое место выделять, это базовый тип с определённым количеством байт, не string же, как и было выделено определённые байты, так они не остались, поправьте, если  не прав

Comment: Только ее в стеке вообще может не быть, она может быть в регистре процессора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что касается локальных переменных, то давайте посмотрим во что превратится этот код после компиляции

```
int a = 5;
Console.WriteLine(a);
a = 10;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

А вот во что, откомпилированный ассемблер

```
mov ecx, 5
call System.Console.WriteLine(Int32)
mov ecx, 10
call System.Console.WriteLine(Int32)
```

Никакого стека, никакой памяти не используется, используется только регистр процессора `ECX`. Так как регистры процессора - это то что существует всегда, то можно сказать, что выделения памяти или создания каких-либо сущностей, потребляющих дополнительные ресурсы компьютера не создается, ни в первом, не во втором случае.

Если же переменная будет членом класса

```
private int a;
```

```
a = 5;
Console.WriteLine(a);
a = 10;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

То получится вот так

```
mov dword ptr [esi+4], 5
mov ecx, [esi+4]
call System.Console.WriteLine(Int32)
mov dword ptr [esi+4], 10
mov ecx, [esi+4]
call System.Console.WriteLine(Int32)
```

`[ESI+4]` - это адрес ячейки памяти, где лежит `a`. Как видно, происходит перезапись участка оперативы, новой памяти не выделяется.